# Exception while Deploying Grails application

Tags: java, grails, tomcat7

I've following Exception while deploying Grails application on tomcat7 on centos7, I'm not able to figure out or understand this issue,
Following is the stacktrace,
Please help me to figure out this issue, thanks in advance!

```
> Jul 25, 2016 2:47:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
> loadClass INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been
> stopped already.  Could not load
> net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following
> stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as
> well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal
> access, and has no functional impact. java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>   at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.keySet(DiskStore.java:610)   at
> net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:817)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> 
> Jul 25, 2016 2:48:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
> loadClass INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been
> stopped already.  Could not load com.mongodb.DBApiLayerBeanInfo.  The
> eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for
> debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
> caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Comment: Try to delete deployed folder in `webapps` and restart the server

Comment: @TarasKohut thanks for reply, I'll try this.

Comment: @TarasKohut I've removed deployed folder as well as data from /work directory still no luck

Comment: Resolved! unfortunately my Mongo service was stopped.